geom_line isn't forming line plot
I'm trying to plot peaks with geom_line, but the plot isn't forming any lines could you tell me what I'm missing?
x<- c("1C","2C","4C")
y<- c(0,70,30)
df<-data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df)+
  aes(x=x,y=y)+
  geom_line()

Image for clarification:


Add group=1 (or any other constant) to your aes(): aes(x=x,y=y, group=1)

@MrFlick I tried to add group=1 as you suggested but it only adds a single line

You were expecting more than one line? What kind of plot exactly are you trying to create? Where are the lines supposed to start and end? Did you want more of a bar chart? ggplot(df) + aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_col()
